# What are Funges?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

I am currently reading up about esoteric programming languages and came across a COS theory question stated as follows:

> Esoteric programming languages can be categorised in a variety of different ways. For each of the
> following categories identify one advantage and one disadvantage associated with languages falling
> within the category:

And the categories given are

```
a) Funges
b) Stateful encoding languages
```

Before commenting on their relative pros and cons, I would first like to know what is a funge? I find it difficult to get information about this term and it also doesn't appear in our textbook (Concepts of Programming Languages, Robert W. Sebesta, 11th ed).

If anyone can either explain it to me or point me to a good source that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's "esoteric". So whatever "funges" are, I don't care until someone can explain it in English. Same for "stateful encoding languages" which means whatever someone makes up.

Comment: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Funge-98